# Saving float values into MySQL database?

Tags: hibernate

I am using MySQL data base need to insert static float values into my table using a Java Bean via (Hibernate). My data does not get inserted even though I use the required float suffix (eg. 0.0F) but the row is inserted as the column data indicates a null.

I need help with getting the correct float values into MySQL as apposed to null(s).
Can the community aid me with code that can assist me or direct me to a relevant example to demonstrate how this is done?

Answer (score 2):

1) what do you mean by `static`. The object you should be inserting shoudn't be static, since the values of a field can change from one object to another.

2) why do you use the `F` suffix. Simply define it in the annotations

```
@Column(name = "float_value")
private float floatVal;
```

Or use the .hbm.xml file, with the object mapping still having `private float floatVal;`

Then simply do:

```
myObject.setFloatVal(0.0);
session.save(myObject);
```